# How to do a selective for loop?

Tags: php, for-loop

I have a complicated scenario where I need to run a for loop and it should run all the time, not dependent on variables, BUT if a variable DOES exist (meaning it doesn't equal '') then I need to check another.  If both conditions are true, then it should continue.  Confusing, but its hard to explain let my try to show you:

$subcat is defined elsewhere before the for loop

```
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($news_posts); ++$i)
    $subcategory = $news_posts[$i]['subcategory'];

    if( $subcat != '' && $subcat == $subcategory){
    CONSEQUENT XYZ.
```

So basically.  I need this for loop to execute XYZ EVERYTIME.  But IF Subcat exists, then it needs to ONLY show the results where subcat is the same as subcategory.

1. Run every time
2. If subcat doesn't exist, show every entry.
3. If subcat DOES exist check if subcat == subcategory
4. If subcat does == subcategory, show every entry where they subcategory is the same as sub cat.

How do do something like this?

Comment: Perhaps I've misunderstood your question, but how about replacing the condition with `!isset($subcat) || $subcat === $subcategory` ?

Comment: Right, raina77ow is saying that the subcat is either blank or it equals subcategory.  I think this is what you're looking for, isn't it?

Comment: Right, if subcat exists (not blank) THEN it should check if subcat is equal to subcategory.  If they are the same, then it should run through the program only showing results where subcat=subcategory.  If subcat is blank, then it should show EVERY result.

Comment: @DanielFein did the answers help?

Answer (score 0):

Test the existence of your variable using isset():
[php man isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($news_posts); ++$i) {
    $subcategory = $news_posts[$i]['subcategory'];

    //Show entry only if subcat is not set OR if it is set and matches the subcategory
    if(!isset($subcat) || ($subcat == $subcategory)) {
        //Do show entry stuff
    }
}
```

Should be self-explanatory, this is the conditional you seem to be looking for. If `$subcat` is set only the iterations that match the subcategory will run the show entry code, otherwise all iterations will run it.

Because isset is a language construct and not a function, and because if the first condition of the statement is true the second is ignored, if `$subcat` is never declared the code above will not raise an error, as opposed to your original code.